# tortoise svn merge and reverted the changes - now merge not show

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise svn to merge changes from trunk to my branch.
One time, I merged the changes from trunk to branch but I did not commit those changes, I reverted all the files. Then I am trying to get the merge changes again, but this time merge is not showing any results. How to get the merge files again?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you did not revert the mergeinfo properties on the main folder you originally merged from, in which case it would show some revisions as already merged. Your question is not entirely clear though, what exactly isn't showing results?